# NSSortDescriptor has no effect on Core Data fetch request

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

My Core Data entity "Entry" has 4 attributes, including the attribute "key", which I want to sort by. "key" is non-optional and unique. Core Data structure:

[image: Core Data structure]

I am fetching objects from Core Data like this:

```
var entries: [NSManagedObjectID : NSManagedObject] = [:]    

class func fetchEntriesfromPersistentStore () {
    
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Entry")
    
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.key, ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    
    do {
        let fetchesEntries = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        entries = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: fetchesEntries.map{ ($0.objectID, $0) })
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch entries. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I also tried the following initialisation of the NSSortDescriptor like in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssortdescriptor/1413572-init):

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "key", ascending: true)
```

---

The resulting dictionary is always in random order, i.e. in different order on every execution. I confirmed that code above is executed. Removing the NSSortDescriptor also has no effect on the results.

I inspected the list `fetchesEntries` before the objects are stored in the dictionary, and it is not sorted.

iOS Deployment Target is 13.4, Swift 5.0, Xcode 11.5, macOS 10.15.5

Comment: I am surprised that this compiles: `NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.key`. This is Cocoa / Objective-C you are talking to. You need an Objective-C key path, not a Swift keypath.

Comment: *The resulting dictionary is always in random order*. Yes, this is not a bug, it's a feature. Dictionaries are unordered by definition.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Entry.key), ascending: true)
```